# Call a method in a specific time of the day

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, time, task

I want to call a method in a specific time of the day without any need to request to any page :

**UPDATE: i done it with the following class and without Task Schedule or something else**

Something like windows schedule

I did it in a class:

```
public class Class1 {

    private const string DummyCacheItemKey = "GagaGuguGigi";

    protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var Result = RegisterCacheEntry();
        if (!Result) {
            Debug.WriteLine("The DummyCacheItem is Alive!");
        }
    }

    public bool RegisterCacheEntry() {
        if (null != HttpContext.Current.Cache[DummyCacheItemKey])
            return false;
        try {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(DummyCacheItemKey, "Test", null, DateTime.MaxValue, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), CacheItemPriority.Normal, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(CacheItemRemovedCallback));

        }catch( Exception Ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Exeption Error: " + Ex);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void CacheItemRemovedCallback(string key, object value, CacheItemRemovedReason reason) {
        Debug.WriteLine("Cache item callback: " + DateTime.Now.ToString() + " Removed!");

        try {
            HitPage();
        }catch(Exception Ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine("HitPage Was unsuccessful: " + Ex);
        }

        // Do the service works


        DoWork();
        //SendMail();

    }

    private const string DummyPageUrl = "http://localhost:53509/Page.cshtml";

    private void HitPage() {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadData(DummyPageUrl);
    }


    protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // If the dummy page is hit, then it means we want to add another item

        // in cache

        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString() == DummyPageUrl) {
            // Add the item in cache and when succesful, do the work.

            RegisterCacheEntry();
        }
    }

    private void DoWork() {
        Debug.WriteLine("Begin DoWork...");
        Debug.WriteLine("Running as: " +
              WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

        DoSomeFileWritingStuff();

        Debug.WriteLine("End DoWork...");
    }


    private void DoSomeFileWritingStuff() {
        Debug.WriteLine("Writing to file...");

        try {
            using (StreamWriter writer =
             new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\Cachecallback.txt", true)) {
                writer.WriteLine("Cache Callback: {0}", DateTime.Now);
                writer.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception x) {
            Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + x);
        }

        Debug.WriteLine("File write successful");
    }
}
```

And here is the explanation of [why i did this?](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc)

Is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Why not just use Task Schedueler and set the time to run the program?

Comment: @Yvette OP means that he wants an event based system rather than a "polling" based system.

Comment: the Task scheduler works every day in a time without requesting to the website or any page??? @MikkelMellumHviid

Answer (score 0):

use "Task Scheduler" to run the programme in a specific time.

Find it by typing "task scheduler" in start menu.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you are actually trying to do here. If you just need to execute some code at given times, use windows scheduler.

If you for some reason need to do this from yur web application you could use http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ and host it within your web application. Just make sure your application pool is set to always run so the task scheduler stays alive.

Comment: i want to do it on a shared hosting! shared hosting doesn't support for Windows services

Comment: if you can control application pool settings you should be able to solve this with quartz.

Answer (score 0):

24 hours timer is working perfectly

```
var DailyTime = "16:59:00";
var timeParts = DailyTime.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

var dateNow = DateTime.Now;
var date = new DateTime(dateNow.Year, dateNow.Month, dateNow.Day,
               int.Parse(timeParts[0]), int.Parse(timeParts[1]), int.Parse(timeParts[2]));
TimeSpan ts;
if (date > dateNow)
   ts = date - dateNow;
else
{
   date = date.AddDays(1);
   ts = date - dateNow;
}

//waits certan time and run the code
Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x) => OnTimer());
```